# Pocketsphinx Android demo error: "Failed to init recognizer java.io.IOException: Failed to initialize recorder. Microphone might already be in use."

Tags: android, voice-recognition, speech-to-text, pocketsphinx, pocketsphinx-android

I have been using Pocketsphinx Android demo and get the error: "Failed to init recognizer java.io.IOException: Failed to initialize recorder. Microphone might already be in use."

What does the error mean and what can I do to fix it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to access microphone when another app is using it in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24170124/unable-to-access-microphone-when-another-app-is-using-it-in-android)

Comment: This means that microphone is already used in another application, you can't do much about it.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev I have closed all other apps using the microphone so it cannot come from another app.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev My app has multiple activities using the microphone, it is when my app switches from the first activity to the second where the problem arises.

Comment: Ok, so you tried to access microphone multiple times yourself, you shouldn't do that.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev I need to access the microphone throughout each activity in the app. Would there be a way to use onPause() / onResume to fix this ?

Comment: recognizer.shutdown() releases the recorder. You can invoke it in onPause().

Answer (score 1):

If you upgrade your Android OS to 6 or it is already 6, you have to ask permission in runtime. Android manifest recorder permission is not enough after Android OS 6. It will give this error if you do not ask permission.