# Detect if another app is requesting the microphone

Tags: android, audio-recording

I have seen multiple questions on SO that say it is impossible to see when another app wants to use the microphone ([Unable to access microphone when another app is using it in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24170124/unable-to-access-microphone-when-another-app-is-using-it-in-android)). However, I know it is possible because Shazam has an "Auto" function that allows the exact functionality I want: to continuously listen to audio when other apps are not using the microphone.

Currently, when I use my app and use an app like Snapchat, I am unable to record a video with audio because Snapchat does not take the mic over. However, as I said before, in this case Shazam's Auto feature works fine.

So how do I listen for when other apps want to use the mic? I am fine using something that is a "hack" as long as it does not require rooting the phone or similar.

EDIT:
Shazam never had this functionality, their app fails to relinquish the mic to other applications while it is running.

Comment: have you got a solution ?,i am struggling for that

Comment: @KareemElsayed I posted the best solution I have at the moment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently the best solution I have. There is no way to listen for other applications requesting the microphone, so I created a `UsageStats` checker that runs every 3 seconds to see if the currently open app has the ability to request audio. Please let me know if you have something better or make improvements to this.

Note: You must add the permissions to the app manifest:

`<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />`

```
    AppOpsManager appOps = (AppOpsManager) getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
    int mode = appOps.checkOpNoThrow(AppOpsManager.OPSTR_GET_USAGE_STATS,
            android.os.Process.myUid(), getPackageName());

    if (mode != AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    if (otherAppAudioTimer != null) {
        otherAppAudioTimer.cancel();
    }

    otherAppAudioTimer = new Timer();
    otherAppAudioTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            UsageStatsManager usm = (UsageStatsManager) getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
            long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            final List<UsageStats> queryUsageStats = usm.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_YEARLY, now - (1000 * 60 * 60), now);
            if (queryUsageStats != null && queryUsageStats.size() > 0) {
                SortedMap<Long, UsageStats> mySortedMap = new TreeMap<>();
                for (UsageStats usageStats : queryUsageStats) {
                    mySortedMap.put(usageStats.getLastTimeUsed(), usageStats);
                }
                if (!mySortedMap.isEmpty()) {
                    String currentApp = mySortedMap.get(mySortedMap.lastKey()).getPackageName();
                    boolean hasRecordAudio = getPackageManager()
                            .checkPermission(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, currentApp)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

                    if (getApplicationContext().getPackageName().equals(currentApp)) {
                        Log.e("hasAudio", "Current app is self");
                        return;
                    }


                    if (hasRecordAudio) {
                        //the current app can record audio
                    } else {
                        //the current app cannot record audio
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }, 0, 3000);
```

Comment: From [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html): `PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS` . . . is a system-level permission and will not be granted to third-party apps. However . . . the user of the device can grant permission through the Settings application.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede yes, it is not implictly granted by Android, but in my code the Intent code makes a request to allow the permission if the user has not already. This is also why I need to use the ignore in the permission

Comment: The docs for [`ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS) say that it may not be available on all devices.  In the early days of Lollipop, I read that major manufacturers including Samsung and LG had removed it from many of their devices.  Have you run into problems with this?

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede no, but this is a "hack", there are many things wrong with the method I am using but it is the best way to achieve what I want. When Android offers something that is better I will use it/update this (Aka broadcast listeners just like the `AudioManager`)

Comment: But why check if the current app has the record audio permission? Was it not already granted by the user? Why is that different from Context.checkSelfPermission()?