# How do I stop hogging the microphone

Tags: java, android, android-broadcast, pocketsphinx

**TL;DR: My app is hogging the user's microphone. Can I turn it off automatically whenever another app needs to use the mic?**

I have an Android app that has some really cool microphone functionality, similar to Amazon Alexa, that stays on all the time in a background service. The problem is, my app hogs the users' microphone, making it unusable:

[image]

However, this is terrible application behavior on my behalf, and I want to do my best to avoid it. **Is it possible to be notified when another application requests to use the microphone, so that I can automatically stop my service?**

PS: I am using the Pocketsphinx library for continuous background voice recognition.

Comment: Instead implement a button in your app. Button press recording start, button up recording stop and send the voice clip to pocketsphinx.

Comment: Android P will prevent idle applications from listening to the microphone (source: https://www.theverge.com/2018/3/7/17091104/android-p-prevents-apps-using-mic-camera-idle-background), so you might need to re-think your design anyway (perhaps using @g10dras's suggestion of push-to-activate).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42185088/detect-if-another-app-is-requesting-the-microphone This will work for sure!!

Comment: Why not use the hey google interface?

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky, as I'm not a ware of any API for this. This surely will require system-level APIs to work like an "Ok Google" type of thing.

A viable option would be (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/43623308/603270) to run a Job at regular intervals, checking for foreground apps using `android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS`.

This might suffice. But you could also add things regarding phone calls ([how to detect phone call broadcast receiver in android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5990590/603270)) using `android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE` or media playback (via `Receiver` or maybe even `MediaPlayer` directly).

Answer (score 1):

If you're really wanting to get this thing working, an alternative would be to get an array list of all installed apps on the system and which ones require permission to use the mic or not, then use an accessibility service to monitor the users screen if an app the user just opened requires the mic (which you'll know from the array you just grabbed). From there, disable the mic in your app if their app needs the mic. The background service can then check in intervals of, say, two minutes, to see if the app that required the mic is still open. This is really inefficient. But if you don't care, then this might be a good option.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way to inform another app that you want access to the microphone (so that they release the resources and let you access it). You could however send a broadcast to all other apps ("requesting the microphone"), but the other apps would have to implement this feature (and very few or zero developers will do this).

I would recommend you to simply inform the user that the microphone is currently not available, because you can't do anything else.

Comment: And speaking as one of those other developers who want the mic - what are we supposed to do when another app asks for it?  I work on voip apps, so if we've got the mic, you're on a phone call, and I don't want to give it up.  Unless maybe you've muted the call, or some other set of things that turn out to be a nasty hairball of special cases that virtually no one cares about and are expensive to test.