# Android PocketSphinx Hijacks microphone

Tags: android, voice-recognition, pocketsphinx, pocketsphinx-android

So I installed Pocketsphinx on my app and the keyword function is working great. I followed this tutorial `https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialandroid/` for my setup. The problem I have is that it hijacks the microphone so you can no longer use it for voice to text or anything else as long as it is waiting for the keyword. I know when you use `Ok Google` you can still use voice to text with it. Would someone be able to point me in a direction of how I can use voice command keywords and still be able to use the microphone for other things?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to share audio input (Microphone) stream in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758946/is-it-possible-to-share-audio-input-microphone-stream-in-android)

Comment: Also related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25402434/use-microphone-in-multiple-app-simultaneously-in-android?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: That does not answer my question as OK Google allows you to use other voice input along side of it.

Comment: "OK google" uses separate hardware chip.